# Showing that union of all left cosets is the entire group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be finite group and $H \leq G$. Show that $\bigcup_{X \in G/H} X = G $

#### Attempt:

Let $x \in \bigcup X $, then there is some $X \in G/H $ such that $x \in X$. Say $X = gH$ where $g \in G$. We have that $x = g h $ for some $h \in H$. IT follows that $x \in G$.

Next, for $x \in G$, then $x = x e$ and $ e \in H$ so $x $ lies is some coset ,say $X \in G/H$: $x  \in X \subset \bigcup_{X \in G/H} X $

Is this a correct solution? Probabibly the notation is bothering a bit. Can I write the problem as follows: ? Since $G$ is finite, we can write $G = \{e,g_1,...,g_n \}$ and we know $G/H $ is also finite so can write $G/H = \{ H, g_1H,...,g_kH \}$ and so the problem is asking to prove that

$$ G = \bigcup_{i=0}^k iH $$
??

Comment: This solution loks fine, but rather than saying $x$ lies in some coset $X$, since $xe=x$, and $e\in H$ $x\in xH\in G/H$

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct.  The first part - where you show that $x\in G$ - is unnecessary though.  It should be clear that each coset $X$ is a subset of $G$, and so the union $\bigcup X$ is a subset of $G$.

For the other direction, you're absolutely right.  If $x\in G$, then $x=xe$, so $x\in xH$.

As for your other idea, I don't see any point in explicitly enumerating the elements of the group $G$ as $e,g_1,\dots,g_n$ - in fact, you're using something (the finiteness of the group $G$) that you don't need to use - the statement is true even when $G$ is an infinite group (Why?)

Comment: Thank you! one question: Since the elements $G/H$ form partition of $G$, can I argue as follows: $$ |G| = \Bigg| \bigcup_{X \in \mathcal{L}} X \Bigg| =  \sum_{X \in \mathcal{L}} |X|  = |H| \sum_{X \in \mathcal{L}} 1 = |H| |\mathcal{L}|$$ ?

Comment: where $\mathcal{L} = G/H$

Comment: @Willie Yes you can, but it's overkill for this problem.  In fact, if you can assume that the elements of $G/H$ form a partition of $G$ then it's automatic that their union is $G$ - that's part of what it means to be a partition.

Comment: In fact, showing that $\bigcup_{X\in G/H} X=G$ is part f=of the proof that the elements of $G/H$ partition $G$, so you shouldn't te result about $G/H$ partitioning $G$ here.

Comment: So I dont neew to show what I have in my question since I know $G/H$ partition of $G$ so that it follows what I wrote above in the comments. Correct?

Comment: $G/H$ being a partition of $G$ means that 1) $\bigcup_{X\in G/H} X=G$ and 2) for any $X,Y\in G/H$, $X\cap Y=\emptyset$.  So if you know that, you already know that $\bigcup_{X\in G/H} X=G$.  What is the context of you asking this question?

Comment: proving lagrange theorem